# I Unable to load External Js Files in app.js React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import bootstrap template in react application. all external js files in src/assets/js folder.
and I don't want to put that external JavaScript files in public folder.

already tried with react-helmet and react-script-tag but these are not working.

```
   `<Helmet>
    <script
      src="./assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      async
    ></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </Helmet>`
```

these are all should be in index.js or app.js not in index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the script inside the react component, you can use the following options.

**With hooks**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

**Without Hooks And Class Component**

```
componentDidMount () {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = url;
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```